# svn repository changed

Tags: svn, repository

An external company switched the URL of their repository from `http://ServerA/PathA` to `http://ServerB/PathB`. I should be able to simply relocate my working copy to point to the new address via

```
svn switch --relocate http://ServerA/PathA http://ServerB/PathB
```

but I get the error message "Relocate can only change the repository part of an URL". While some others seem to have this problem as well (there are dozens of posts on SE as well), I did not find any solutions (beside checking out from the new URL and manually copying over all changed files).

The current debian-stable svn is 1.6.12.

Any ideas?

Comment: hello, just this:
`svn relocate http://ServerB/PathB`
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html

Comment: unfortunately, svn relocate itself is available since 1.7 only.

Answer (score 0):

so, the solution was a two-stage approach. I first switched the server, then the path.

```
svn switch --relocate http://ServerA/PathA http://ServerB/PathA
svn switch http://ServerB/PathB
```

This actually worked for me.